# Python - How to remove duplicates in huge CSV file (200+ Million rows)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, duplicates

We made an Image recognition API that accepts image URL and responds an image description. This process takes about 5-20 seconds.
I have a huge CSV file with 200+ million rows of image URLs scraped from different sources. I found that the CSV file has duplicate image URLs from different sources. So I don't need to send all the URLs to image recognition API, I need to send only unique URLs to the API but I need to populate response from API to all the rows.

I read the CSV file in chunks of 100K rows and created a set of unique Image URLs and process them in API and again populate the results back to the CSV file. But It ended up in memory issues (16 GB RAM), I can't able to create a set of unique Image URLs with 200+ million rows.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're sticking with the CSV rather than use a database where you could set restrictions for uniqueness? It would also be much more efficient to run searches rather than scanning through the entire CSV

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189684/remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-csv-file could help

Comment: Yeah, I agree its easy process data from the database than from CSV file. But they provided me the CSV and to process it.

Comment: Sort using an external (out of memory) method. Then removing duplicates is trivial because they will next to each other.

Comment: Ok, but you could just throw it into an SQLite database or something. This has minimal setup

Comment: Absolutely agree with @roganjosh, get all these urls into a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

#### SQL Select Distinct

Load the CSV file into a database and us SQL Select Distinct and export the query result as a Csv file. Some database let you define a CSV file as a table and let you run SQL queries on the CSV file

Select distinct URL from UrlTable

#### Sort the File

You could

- Sort the file on the URL using your operating systems sort command (both Windows and Linux have Sort commands).
- Read the file and check if the URL is different from the last URL. You only need check the URL when it changes

Answer (score -1):

Not sure whether this approach might be suitable for such a huge file. But, you can give it a try.

```
import csv
entries = set()

with open("HugeCSVfile.csv", 'r') as lookuplist:
    for col in csv.reader(lookuplist):
        key = (col[0].lower()) # add rows you want to compare and remove the duplicates.
        if key not in entries:
            entries.add(key)
            print(key)
```